# React use onChange from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I took over a project from a coworker that does not longer work for us.
He has done things a bit different than I would have done it and now I'm pretty confused.

I have a parent component where I need to listen for changes made to the child and afterwards work with them in the **parent** component

Parent (I "obfuscated" props and fields due to company rules):

```js
interface ParentProps {
  prop1: string;
  prop2?: string;
  prop3?: boolean;
}

function handleChange(value: String) {
  console.log(value);
}

export const Parent: FunctionComponent<ParentProps> = ({
  prop1,
  prop2,
  prop3 = isTrue(prop1),
}) => {
  return (
    <Children
      prop1Val={prop1}
      prop2Val={prop2}
      prop3Val={prop3}
      maskSettings={{
        mask: '##00 **** **** **** **** **** **** **** **',
        definitions: {
          '#': /[A-Z]/,
          '*': /[A-Z0-9]/,
        },
        prepare: (input: string) => input.toUpperCase(),
      }}
    >
    </Children>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

Children:

```js
import { IMaskMixin } from 'react-imask';
import {
  FormControl,
  TextField,
  TextFieldProps,
  FormHelperText,
} from '@material-ui/core';

type ChildrenInputComponentProps = ChildrenProps | TextFieldProps;

const InputComponent: FunctionComponent<TextFieldProps> = (props) => (
  <TextField {...props}/>
);

const ChildrenInputComponent: FunctionComponent<ChildrenInputComponentProps> = IMaskMixin(
  InputComponent
);

interface ChildrenInputProps {
  prop1: string;
  prop2?: string;
  prop3?: boolean;
  maskSettings: MaskProps;
}

export const Children: FunctionComponent<ChildrenInputProps> = ({
  prop1,
  prop2,
  prop3 = isTrue(prop1),
  maskSettings,
}) => (
        <div>
          <ChildrenInputComponent
            {...maskSettings}
            unmask={true}
            onAccept={(unmasked: string) =>
              !!!!!!!!
              
              use the handleChange from parent
              
              !!!!!!!!
            }
            InputLabelProps={{
              shrink: true,
            }}
            fullWidth
            label={prop2}
            required={prop3}
          />
          </div>
);

export default Children;
```

How would I access the handleChange in this situation?
Thank you already!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `handleChange` from the parent to the child as props -

```
<Children onChange={handleChange} ... />
```

then call it in the child -

```
onAccept={(unmasked: string) =>
   props.onChange(unmasked);
}
```

edit -

you'll need to add `onChange` to your props object -

```
export const Children: FunctionComponent<ChildrenInputProps> = ({
  prop1,
  prop2,
  prop3 = isTrue(prop1),
  maskSettings,
  onChange, // <!--- here
}) => (
```

then call it like -

```
onAccept={(unmasked: string) =>
  onChange(unmasked);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, so far so good.

But I mainly stuck on the part when it comes to access the onChange method.
When I simply jam 
<Children onChange=...../> 
into the parent component I get "onChange does not exist on Children"

Comment: right, because you are destructuring your props at the top of Children.  You'll need to add a `onChange` reference to the props object

Comment: Thanks!
I just had the wrong type declared inside my props.

Thanks bud, sometimes it needs someone to show you the error right in front of you